# Do I need to retain Sharepoint usage analysis log files

Tags: sharepoint, logging

Our Sharepoint installation currently has 30Gb of Usage Analysis Log file - these date back about six months.

I have configured Sharepoint to do Usage Analysis Processing every night, so I am wondering whether I need to keep these files for so long.

Sharepoint doesn't seem to clean up these files automatically - I think six months ago I had to clear out logs due to disk space issues.

So my question is, do I need to retain these files in order to get decent usage analysis reports, or can I delete them as soon as the usage analysis processing has completed?

Answer (score -1):

I would try to compress them with 7-zip and keep them around and see if they affect anything.

Comment: -1 - that isn't an answer to the question of whether I need to retain the files.  I don't want to delete to find out if it causes a problem - I want to delete in the secure knowledge that it won't cause a problem.